# How to customize PHP configuration per Virtual Host under Plesk

Tags: php, debian, php.ini

i have a dev server (debian) managed via Plesk (9.5.2).

Im wondering if is possible to change the php.ini settings for a single host while PHP is running as FastCgi/CGI application.

If i run PHP as apache module, i can do it via vhost.conf, for example:

```
<Directory /var/www/vhosts/example.com/httpdocs>
    php_admin_flag engine on
    php_admin_value open_basedir "/var/www/vhosts/example.com/httpdocs:/var/www/vhosts/drupal:/tmp"
</Directory>
```

*customize* the open_basedir just for the *example.com* domain, but works only if i run php as apache module; for others motivations, i **need php as a FastCGI/CGI**.

I cant edit directly the php.ini, becose this would affect all my domains.

Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[The PHP manual specifies where you can change each directive](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.list.php).

As far as using ini_set or .htaccess you may be out of luck, as according to the docs:

> php_admin_value name value
>   Sets the value of the specified directive. This can not be used in .htaccess files. Any directive type set with php_admin_value can not be overridden by .htaccess or ini_set(). To clear a previously set value use none as the value.

You might be able to fudge it by writing a script in your CGI directory which sets environment variables, and then starts PHP, instead of invoking PHP directly.  This is detailed at http://www.fastcgi.com/drupal/node/5?q=node/10 and provides the following pointer for more info:

> The README.FastCGI file, located in the PHP source, provides additional details on these and some other useful variables.